# Getting an error inputting numbers into my console app

Tags: c#, .net

I get the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
> correct format.    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str,
> NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info,
> Boolean parseDecimal)    at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s,
> NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)    at
> System.Int32.Parse(String s)    at weatherApp.Program.Main(String[]
> args) in C:\Users\decagon\source\repos\weatherApp\Program.cs:line 15
> Press any key to continue . . .

Here's my code:

```
namespace weatherApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("what is the Value of Temperature in Celcius? ");
            Console.Read();
            int temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (temp > 24 && temp <50 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wear a short and light Cloth");

            }

            if (temp  > 50 && temp < 59)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dont Wear Clothes, Weather is too hot");
            }

            if (temp > 60 && temp <= 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are Dead, because you have reached the boiling point");
            }
        
            if (temp < 24)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are also dead!!!!!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the error message?

Comment: For future questions please re-read [mre] guidance - there is way too much unrelated code in the post...

Comment: what are the unrelated codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete Console.Read(),you are reading the line when you assign temp.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem lies here:

```cs
Console.Read(); // Problem
int temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

For example, when you press the number "5" on your keyboard and then press "Enter", the input stream will receive these characters (on Windows):

```
'5' '\r' '\n'
```

The `Console.Read()` will grab the '5' (and throw it away). All that's left for the `Console.ReadLine()` at that point is the "\r\n" which it returns as an empty string. And that empty string cannot be parsed with `int.Parse`.

Comment: thanks Guys, all your answers are valid and i have been able to resolve the bug

Answer (score 0):

Remove Console.Read():
It will work fine so:

```
namespace weatherApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("what is the Value of Temperature in Celcius? ");
            int temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (temp > 24 && temp <50 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wear a short and light Cloth");
            }

            if (temp  > 50 && temp < 59)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dont Wear Clothes, Weather is too hot");
            }

            if (temp > 60 && temp <= 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are Dead, because you have reached the boiling point"); 
            }
            
            if (temp < 24)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You are also dead!!!!!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```